# what are the steps to be required to start with spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>2018Spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>2018Spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Is this even a question?

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.spring.model;

import java.util.List;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection="courses")
public class Course {

    @Id
    private String _id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String pass;
    private String lecture;
    private List<ObjectId> subjects;


    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getPass() {
        return pass;
    }
    public void setPass(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }
    public String getLecture() {
        return lecture;
    }
    public void setLecture(String lecture) {
        this.lecture = lecture;
    }
    public List<ObjectId> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }
    public void setSubjects(List<ObjectId> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }










}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://start.spring.io/

You can create a project here and it'll take care of all the configurations to start.